# Xcode support of lambda functions

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11

I have a program coded in VS that I'm trying to port over to Xcode. There are several issues I have ran into including use of lambda functions. Since Xcode uses gcc 4.2 and thus doesn't support C++11, will I not be able to use any lambda functions?

If I want to work on the code from my laptop without rewriting much of the code, will I have to install gcc 4.6 and compile using the terminal?

Comment: Compiling GCC 4.6.1 on MacOSX is very straight-forward. Maybe that's an option.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Just to verify, I can't update gcc and configure Xcode to use it?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, and it wouldn't be worth it. Just install the new build into `/usr/local` or something like that. I'm sure you can configure XCode to use the new compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few options:

- Re-write your code to the C++ 2003 standard.
- Install GCC that supports C++11 features being used in the code and not use Xcode (you may use other IDEs, for example QtCreator or Eclipse CDT).
- Wait for Xcode that comes with LLVM C++ compiler that supports C++11 features.